# current drawn by led increase with more leds you put in parallel??against V=IR?

Tags: current, ohms-law

current drawn by led increase with more leds you put which i saw in a video about thyristor ,but more leds means more resistance which means lesser current which is not true as per the video(https://youtu.be/4N1uLth1o9o )1:50-2:00that does not fall true how and why.
PS -the channel is GreatScott's so its reliable

Comment: LEDs are not resistors.

Comment: if you run 4 hoses into a bucket, you can fill it 4x faster. if you run those same 4 hoses end to end to the bucket, it will take longer to fill than one hose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LEDs he is using have an internal resistor or constant-current chip (there are no external series resistors as is normal).

When you connect them in parallel across a fixed voltage, **each** will draw a certain amount of current (depending on the LED and the voltage). Put 5 similar ones in parallel and you get about 5x the current that you get with one.

Comment: the LEDs are plain jane LEDs, no resistors or CC

Answer (score 1):

More LEDs (or resistors) in parallel means more paths for current to flow = less effective resistance.

Connecting resistors in series will increase the total resistance - total resistance will be the sum of the individual resistor values.

Answer (score 1):

> Current drawn by led increase with more leds you put which i saw in a
>   video about thyristor.

The LEDs in the video were connected in parallel.

They are now acting like 4 times the original load (Single LED). The intention in the video is to simply I increase the load  is about Thyristor latching.

The LEDs are also turned on without a current limiting element. It is not a good idea. The supply voltage there is just 2.7 V right about the forward voltage drop plus the additional drop in thyristor.
[image]

> But more LEDs means more resistance

Hypothetically, yes if you connect them in series (considering the leads resistance in m ohms).  Same way when you connect in parallel, it will be lesser than single LED one. But the **change will be of no use** to consider.

Connecting more LEDs in the video is like turning on more bulbs in the house. The current will have to increase.

Comment: _"The supply voltage there is just 2.7 V right about the forward voltage drop."_ - Red LEDs typically drop about 1.8 V, not 2.7 V; the difference is dropped in the thyristor.

Comment: @marcelm I bit my foot